# Changing the values of R, G, B in the image takes a long time

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm going to change the (r,g,b) values of the pixels in the image. I have 500 images with a size of 1048 x 2048 and there is 1 label for each image with the same size. The (r,g,b) values of each pixel of the labels are either (255,255,255) or (0,0,0). I check the (r,g,b) values of each pixel of each label and if it was (255, 255 ,255), I change the (r,g,b) values of the same pixel of the corresponding image. I wrote the code in two ways, but unfortunately it takes a long time to execute. I use cv2.imwrite at the end of the code or in each step, and it takes a long time in both cases. Did I make a mistake or is there a way to do it faster? Thanks.

```
Path = ''
searchlbl   = os.path.join( Path , "LABEL"   , "*" , "*" , "*_LBL.png" )
searchimg   = os.path.join( Path , "IMG"   , "*" , "*" , "*_IMG.png" )
imgFine = glob.glob( searchimg )
lblFine = glob.glob( searchlbl )
imgFine.sort()
lblFine.sort()
for i in range (0,500):
lbl = cv2.imread(lblFine[i])
img = cv2.imread(imgFine[i])
for m in range (0,1024):
    for n in range(0,2048):
        lbl_num=lbl[m,n]
        if (lbl_num[0] == 255):

            img_num=img[m,n]
            YKOM = img_num[0]

            if   (65<YKOM<75 ):
                img[m,n] = (0,0,0)
                #cv2.imwrite(imgFine[i], img)
                red = red + 1

            elif   (100<YKOM<110 ):
                img[m,n] = (0,0,0)
                #cv2.imwrite(imgFine[i], img)
                white = white + 1

            elif   (19<YKOM<28 ):
                img[m,n] = (0,0,0)
                #cv2.imwrite(imgFine[i], img)
                black = black + 1

            elif   (92<YKOM<99 ):
                img[m,n] = (0,0,0)
                #cv2.imwrite(imgFine[i], img)
                yellow = yellow + 1

            elif   (15<YKOM<20 ):
                img[m,n] = (0,0,0)
                #cv2.imwrite(imgFine[i], img)
                blue = blue + 1
            cv2.imwrite(imgFine[i], img)
        else:

            continue
print(i)
```

I also changed the code this way:

```
for i in range (0,500):
lbl1 = Image.open(lblFine[i])
lbl = lbl1.load()
img1 = Image.open(imgFine[i])
img = img1.load()

for m in range (0,2048):
    for n in range(0,1024):
        lbl_num=lbl[m,n]
        if (lbl_num[0] == 255):

            img_num=img[m,n]
            YKOM = img_num[0]


            if   (65<YKOM<75 ):
                img[m,n] = (0,0,0)
                #cv2.imwrite(imgFine[i], img)

            elif   (100<YKOM<110 ):
                img[m,n] = (0,0,0)
                #cv2.imwrite(imgFine[i], img)

            elif   (19<YKOM<28 ):
                img[m,n] = (0,0,0)
                #cv2.imwrite(imgFine[i], img)

            elif   (92<YKOM<99 ):
                img[m,n] = (0,0,0)
                #cv2.imwrite(imgFine[i], img)

            elif   (15<YKOM<20 ):
                img[m,n] = (0,0,0)
                #cv2.imwrite(imgFine[i], img)

            img1.save(imgFine[i])
        else:

            continue
print(i)
```

Comment: Try processing your pixels simultaneously. A pixel can be a tuple (m,n)pixel (0,0) is the upper left of the image, pixel (1048,2048) is the bottom right of the image. One less for loop may speed things up.

Comment: See e.g. [array programming](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/)

Comment: further, your code suggests that you tried to write an image multiple times (inside the loops), rather than once. that just makes no sense. -- you use variables like `red` and `white`, that are never initialized, and never used beyond the increment. why?

Comment: You are saving the image each time in the loop. Just save the image at the end of the process. Also check for logical indexing it will drastically reduce LoC.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz Thanks for your attention. This code is part of a larger code. I used these variables for a specific purpose and forgot to delete them in my question.

Comment: @jlandercy Thank you for your attention. I tried both modes and it takes a long time in both modes.